# How to do a unit-test in Handler layer in go?(Using gorm,,gin)

Tags: unit-testing, go, http, go-gorm, go-gin

Recently I started writing unit tests on go.I received a task to conduct tests on all layers.I did it successfully on the repository and service layer, but there were problems on the handlers.I corny just don't understand how to write it here.

```
func (h *Handler) createAddress(c *gin.Context) error {
    var (
        data *schema.AddressRequest
        err  error
    )

    if err = c.BindJSON(&data); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if err = data.ValidateAddress(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    res, err := h.services.Address.Create(c.Request.Context(), data, c.ClientIP())
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return schema.Respond(res, c)
}
```

here is a certain function that I am testing

```
func TestCreateAddress(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("Success", func(t *testing.T) {
        addressData := &schema.AddressRequest{
            Country:   "Kazakhstan",
            City:      "Almaty",
            District:  "Medeu",
            PostIndex: "050000",
            Street:    "Abay",
            Building:  "123",
            Floor:     "4",
            Office:    "42",
        }

        mockAddressService := new(serviceMocks.Address)
        mockAddressService.On("Create", mock.Anything, addressData, mock.AnythingOfType("string")).Return(&model.Address{}, nil)

        mockContext, _ := gin.CreateTestContext(httptest.NewRecorder())
        mockContext.Request, _ = http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, "/api/v1/address", nil)
        mockContext.Set("ClientIP", "127.0.0.1")

        handler := &Handler{
            services: &service.Services{
                Address: mockAddressService,
            },
        }

        err := handler.createAddress(mockContext)
        assert.NoError(t, err)

        mockAddressService.AssertExpectations(t)
    })

    t.Run("Bad", func(t *testing.T) {
        addressData := &schema.AddressRequest{
            Country:   "",
            City:      "",
            District:  "",
            PostIndex: "",
            Street:    "",
            Building:  "",
            Floor:     "",
            Office:    "",
        }

        mockAddressService := new(serviceMocks.Address)

        mockContext, _ := gin.CreateTestContext(httptest.NewRecorder())
        mockContext.Request, _ = http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, "/api/v1/address", nil)
        mockContext.Set("ClientIP", "127.0.0.1")

        handler := &Handler{
            services: &service.Services{
                Address: mockAddressService,
            },
        }

        err := handler.createAddress(addressData)
        assert.Error(t, err)

        mockAddressService.AssertExpectations(t)
    })
}
```

here is the test, and it comes out with the error below

```
User
=== RUN   TestCreateAddress
=== RUN   TestCreateAddress/Success
[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Running in "debug" mode. Switch to "release" mode in production.
 - using env:   export GIN_MODE=release
 - using code:  gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)

    address_test.go:43: 
            Error Trace:    C:/Users/r.ilebaev/GolandProjects/agent/internal/delivery/http/v1/address_test.go:43
            Error:          Received unexpected error:
                            invalid request
            Test:           TestCreateAddress/Success

    address_test.go:45: FAIL:   Create(string,*schema.AddressRequest,mock.AnythingOfTypeArgument)
                at: [C:/Users/r.ilebaev/GolandProjects/agent/internal/delivery/http/v1/address_test.go:30]
    address_test.go:45: FAIL: 0 out of 1 expectation(s) were met.
            The code you are testing needs to make 1 more call(s).
            at: [C:/Users/r.ilebaev/GolandProjects/agent/internal/delivery/http/v1/address_test.go:45]
--- FAIL: TestCreateAddress (0.00s)
    --- FAIL: TestCreateAddress/Success (0.00s)


FAIL


Process finished with the exit code 1
```

I'm not asking for any help on how to fix the code, but judging by the way I write and what functions I'm testing, I'd like to understand some general principle for testing get,post, put and delete requests and functions at the handel level that use the gin and gorm package

at the end I will throw off the very function to which the handler is referred

```
func (s *AddressService) Create(
    ctx context.Context,
    address *schema.AddressRequest,
    clientIP string,
) (*model.Address, error) {
    if address == nil {
        return nil, werr.ErrParseErrorBody
    }

    res, err := s.repos.Address.Create(ctx, address.ToModel())
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return res, err
}
```

....................................................................................................................